# Sql Server 2008 Recursive Stored Proc

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, recursion

I need to create a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 that will update a table based on some value.  The trick here is that I need to recursively search the table until I find the value I am looking for, then update the current record.  For example, I have an Employees table that contains 3 columns:

EmployeeId

ManagerId

FamilyId

For every EmployeeId in the table, I want to get its ManagerId.  Then, if the ManagerID != 0, go and get the ManagerId of the current ManagerId (each ManagerId will point to an EmployeeId) – continue with this until I get to the top level manager ( where ManagerId  == 0).

Once I find the top level manager, I want to update the FamilyId column in the original record that started the process with the value of the last EmployeeId of the above process.

Basically I need to do this with every record in the table.  I am trying set the FamilyId to the value of the root manager for all employees and managers within the hierarchy.

I’m not sure if I should use a cursor or a CTE to get this done – or just do it in code.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: you should post this question in stackexchange [dba experts site](http://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Sandy - This is programming question not a question about administration of databases.

Comment: Doesn't it follow from your description that `FamilyId` will be the same for all 'subordinates' of an arbitrary 'root' employee? If so, why always go to the top of the tree?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could also use a recursive CTE.

```
;WITH Hierarchy
     As (SELECT EmployeeId AS _EmployeeId,
                ManagerId  AS _ManagerId,
                EmployeeId AS _FamilyId
         FROM   @Employee
         WHERE  ManagerId = 0
         UNION ALL
         SELECT e.EmployeeId,
                e.ManagerId,
                h._FamilyId
         FROM   @Employee e
                JOIN Hierarchy h
                  ON h._EmployeeId = e.ManagerId)
UPDATE @Employee
SET    FamilyId = _FamilyId
FROM   Hierarchy h
WHERE  EmployeeId = _EmployeeId
```

Comment: +1, absolutely. I was just going to do that myself. Saved me the trouble, thanks. :) Recursive CTE seems simply born for the task.

Comment: @Andriy - Shame that it doesn't allow the recursive CTE itself to be Updatable so it requires a Join back onto the original table though (unless there is some way of doing this?)

Comment: @Martin: Wouldn't say for sure, but I doubt there is such a way. Given the CTE is reading from more than one table, the engine would have hard time deciding which table was supposed to be updated.

Comment: @Andriy - And actually it would probably have to read the whole table into a spool for halloween protection anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the replys.  I am going to give this a shot.  Am I limited on the number of recursions using the CTE?

Comment: @Scott - Yes. By default it will go down 100 levels. If you need more add `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)`

Answer (score 2):

Here's my first stab at it.  I hope I understood your requirements.

```
declare @Employee table (
    EmployeeId int not null 
    , ManagerId int not null
    , FamilyId int null
)

--       1       6
--      / \     / \
--     2   3    7 8
--    / \
--    4 5

insert @Employee values (1, 0, null) 
insert @Employee values (2, 1, null) 
insert @Employee values (3, 1, null) 
insert @Employee values (4, 2, null) 
insert @Employee values (5, 2, null) 
insert @Employee values (6, 0, null) 
insert @Employee values (7, 6, null) 
insert @Employee values (8, 6, null) 

-- the data before the update       
select * from @Employee

-- initial update to get immediate managers
update Employee
set FamilyId = Manager.EmployeeId
from @Employee Employee
inner join @Employee Manager on Manager.EmployeeId = Employee.ManagerId

-- the data after the first update     
select * from @Employee

-- do more updates until done
while exists (
    select * 
    from @Employee 
    where (
        FamilyId is not null 
        and FamilyId not in (
            select EmployeeId from @Employee where ManagerId = 0
        )
    )
) 
begin
    update Employee
    set FamilyId = Manager.ManagerId
    from @Employee Employee
    inner join @Employee Manager on Manager.EmployeeId = Employee.FamilyId
    where (
        Employee.FamilyId is not null 
        and Employee.FamilyId not in (
            select EmployeeId from @Employee where ManagerId = 0
        )
    )
end

-- the data after all updates
select * from @Employee
```

I'm sure there are more clever ways

Comment: ... In particular, if you were using SQL 2008's HierarchyId, I'm pretty sure you could accomplish this in one line!

Comment: +1 Nicely formatted answer and I borrowed your table population code!

Comment: @Martin - And +1 right back atcha for the CTE solution and for teaching me a new term: "Halloween protection" =)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect I would call into a user defined function (UDF) for this. The UDF would call into itself recursively.

Try googling for : recursive UDF sql server

This link seems to give an example (although they do note that as of SQL 2000, you can only recurse 32 levels deep.)
http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2003/11/21/588.aspx

Sorry that I don't have more time to devote to your question right now. If it's still an issue tomorrow, I'll devote more time to an explanation.